# Start a service when phone reboot completed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to Start a service when phone reboot completed. I will install my app but will not launch it.
I have proceed with the following ways using **Broadcast Receiver** listening to **BOOT_COMPLETED** intent.

My Receiver is as follows...

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   static final String TAG = "MyReceiver"; 
     @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.d(TAG, "******* OnReceive");
      Log.d(TAG, "Boot Completed Caught");
      context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
      }
    }
```

In Manifest I have added the following lines of code:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <service android:name="MyService"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.logic.MyService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


  <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:enabled="true"  android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But receiver is not listening once boot is completed. Remember I have only installed my app but never launch it.But my requirement is such that I should not launch my app after installing it in my device. Anybody can help me on this.

I googled it and found that as I have not launched my app it is in ***stopped state*** and boot completed intent is ignoring my receiver. The below links that might help you in understanding my issue:
          http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/activating-applications/

Comment: You've posted the answer in your own question. Launch your app once from the launcher.

Comment: More details here: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Answer (score 0):

the  service  and MyReceiver must be  full packagename,
like this